# Нужно ли в этом предложении выделять запятыми "чисто из любопытства"?

Tags: запятые

Один раз, чисто из любопытства, решил узнать, где же эта тройка тренируется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, обособлено пояснение.

Такие случаи зависят от автора, от того, какой смысл он придаёт фразе и как произносит - с паузой или без, но здесь пояснение после обстоятельства **один раз** перед сказуемым просто просит паузы, акцент - **"Один раз, из любопытства**"

Без пояснения было бы так: Один раз решил узнать чисто из любопытства, где же эта тройка тренируется. Здесь акцент на  "**узнать из любопытства"**, хотя при желании можно и здесь поставить запятую.